# Shell string with double quotes - RTC command

Tags: bash, shell, rtc

I am trying to run a RTC 4.x command to add components to a workspace.  The list of components have spaces in the names so they need to be surrounded by quotes.  I am storing this list in a simple string variable:

`COMPONENTS="\"TestComp\" \"Common Component\""`

When I just echo out COMPONENTS it displays correctly, but when I use it in a scm command odd things happen to the quotes.  I am running this in Jenkins so I can get some additional output, but the same thing happens when I run it on the command line so this is not a Jenkins issue.

From the console log:

```
+ COMPONENTS='"TestComp" "Common Component"'
+ echo '"TestComp"' '"Common' 'Component"'
"TestComp" "Common Component"
```

The command is trying to run the following:

`+ scm workspace add-components TEST_Workspace -s Test_Stream '"TestComp"' '"Common' 'Component"'`

Which produces:

```
Problem running 'workspace add-components':
Unmatched component ""Common".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you need to use an array to store items that may themselves contain whitespace:

```
components=("TestComp" "Common Component")
scm workspace add-components TEST_Workspace -s Test_Stream "${components[@]}"
```

Quoting an array expansion indexed with `@` produces a sequence of words, one per element of the array, rather than a single word.

Comment: Good thought, but I had tried the array route as well.  This produces similar results depending on how I play with the quotes.  For example: `components=("TestComp" "Common Component")` results in a `com.ibm.team.scm.common.ComponentNotInWorkspaceException: Component 'TestComp' is not in workspace` error.  This `components=("TestComp" "'Common Component'")` produces `Unmatched component "'Common Component'".`

Comment: How would you call `scm` if you were specifying the components manually, without trying to store them in a variable? The first error you show (for the code that I claim should work) looks more like a problem with the setup than with the `bash` command.

Comment: @JimG Did you use double-quotes around the array reference (as in `"${components[@]}"`)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, I put double quotes around the array reference.  @chepner If I were calling the command manually it would be: `scm workspace add-components TEST_Workspace -s Test_Stream TestComp "Common Component"` or it could also be `scm workspace add-components TEST_Workspace -s Test_Stream "TestComp" "Common Component"`

Comment: And that works? There should be no difference between my code and that.

Comment: OK, I started from scratch with a completely new workspace and @chepner your original solution does work.  RTC must have been caching something.  Thanks for the help - I appreciate it!